# Sum same item in one list

Tags: c#

I am still learning C# and I have a problem about list. I was trying to write a code using list. Here is my code

```
List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();

itemList.Add(new Item { ItemID = (int)itemID, ItemQty = (decimal) itemQty });
```

And here is the input for the list

```
index  Item ID & Amount
-------------------------
0      0001         20
1      0002         10
2      0001         30
3      0003         40
```

What I was trying to do is to get the total amount of each ID. For this case, the total amount of Item 0001 is 50.

I know how to sum all item, but I wasn't able to sum the amount for specific item. Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: You could use LINQ's `GroupBy()` with `Sum()`, e.g. `var grouped = itemList.GroupBy(i => i.ItemId).Select(i => new { ItemId=i.Key, Total=i.Sum(item => item.ItemQty) });`. It creates a new anonymous type with ItemId and Total. Later, to get the total for a specific ID, you can do `var sumForId1 = grouped.Where(g => g.ItemId == 1).Select(g => g.Total).Single();`.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL why not post that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted this in a comment but it would be easier to explain / elaborate as an answer, as Ahmad suggested ;)

You could use LINQ's [GroupBy()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) with [Sum()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows (remember `using System.Linq;`)

```
var grouped = itemList.GroupBy(i => i.ItemId).Select(i => new { ItemId=i.Key, Total=i.Sum(item => item.ItemQty) });
```

The above line groups `itemList` based on ItemIds, and then creates a new [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) with ItemId and the sum of ItemQty's (Total).

Later, to get the total for a specific ID, you can do:

```
var sumForId1 = grouped.Where(g => g.ItemId == 1).Select(g => g.Total).Single();
```

Edit to add an alternative:

As Ahmad suggests in the comments, another method (quicker for lookups involving huge lists) is to use [ToDictionary<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows:

```
var grouped = itemList.GroupBy(i => i.ItemID).ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Sum(item => item.ItemQty));      
//doesn't matter if ItemID is string or int here

var sumForId1 = grouped[1];     //or if ItemID is string, grouped["1"]
```

Comment: Thank you! this is what I was trying to do

Comment: @HelmiNandani and @KeyurPATEL, this can be enhanced so the look-up is easier and more efficient by using a dictionary. By adding `.ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Total)` to the end of `grouped` query, you will get a `Dictionary<int, decimal>`. Then you can loop over the dictionary and print the values or use `grouped[1]` to get the value for the item with key of 1, rather than using another query to look-up the value. I'm not sure if your key is an int, might be a string, but the idea is the same.

Comment: @AhmadMageed Ok I will try this one as well, thanks for the advice

Answer (score -1):

If we have a class

```
class Item
{
    public int ItemID;
    public decimal ItemQty;
}
```

Then this is one possible solution

```
void Main()
{
    List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();

    itemList.Add(new Item { ItemID = 1, ItemQty = 20m });
    itemList.Add(new Item { ItemID = 2, ItemQty = 10m });
    itemList.Add(new Item { ItemID = 1, ItemQty = 30m });
    itemList.Add(new Item { ItemID = 3, ItemQty = 40m });

    var itemGroup = itemList.GroupBy(i => i.ItemID).Select(g => new { ItemID = g.Key, TotalQty = g.Select(j => j.ItemQty).Sum() });
    foreach (var i in itemGroup)
        Console.WriteLine($"{i.ItemID}: {i.TotalQty}");
}
```

.